# Django/jQuery Datatables access to datatable parameters

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I've been using jQuery dataTables a little bit, and I used to access to dataTable informations. This time, I decided to add pagination at the beginning and at the end, and python raise this error. How can I access to the first element of the dict ? Maybe by using an other method ?

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'iDisplayStart'
```

**My view**

```
@csrf_exempt
def lexeme_to_json(request):
    query = request.session.get('queryset')
    search = request.GET.get('sSearch', '')
    sort_by = int(request.GET.get('iSortCol_0', '0'))
    asc = request.GET.get('sSortDir_0', 'asc') == 'asc'
    display_all = request.GET.get('iDisplayLength') == '-1'
    start = int(request.GET['iDisplayStart']) # crashes right here
    end = start + int(request.GET['iDisplayLength'])
```

**JS/jQuery datatable configuration**

```
   $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "dom": "<'#datatableFirstLine'<'row'<'col-lg-3'i><'col-lg-3 offset-lg-6'p>>>" +
               "<'#datatableSecondLine'<'row'<'col-lg-3'l><'col-lg-5 offset-lg-4'f>>>" +
               "<'#datatableThirdLine'<'row'<'col-lg-12'tr>>>" +
               "<'#datatableFourthLine'<'row'<'col-lg-3'i><'col-lg-3 offset-lg-6'p>>>",
        "aoColumns": [
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "1%"},
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "12%"},
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "12%"},
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "1%"},
            {"bSortable": true, "sWidth": "1%"},
            {"bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false, "sWidth": "3%"},
            {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "7%"},
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "lexeme_to_json/",
            "type": "POST"
        }
    });
```

Comment: `iDisplayStart` doesn't exists in `request.GET` hence the `MultiValueDictKeyError`. Are you sure its coming in to `request.GET`?

Comment: How would you access to it otherwise ?

Comment: What do you mean by `how would you access to it otherwise`? Please print `request.GET` in view and show what's it spits out.

Comment: I'm getting an apparently empty dict **<QueryDict: {}>**
Internal Server Error: /pls_edit/lexeme_to_json/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/theo/code/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 77, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'iDisplayStart'

Comment: Well its empty so there will always be key error. I think data table is not sending `iDisplayStart` when you are on first page or pagination can't be activated because of records are less than `iDisplayLength` -> `100`, so if you change it to `start = int(request.GET.get('iDisplayStart', '0'))` which means if `iDisplayStart` not in query params then start from 0 and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, but I need to send data if I want to set my end variable therefore isn't it ?